# Using PATCH Method In Retrofit and @Body Annotation

Tags: android, http, retrofit2, okhttp

**My Url is**

> http://sales.xxxxx.com/api/v2/customers/5101117835

When I use this code the response code is always 500.

**Interface Code**

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@PATCH("customers/{custId}")
Call<GeoTag> postGeoTagData (@Body geoTagUserData geoTag, @Path("custId") String id, @Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

**In Activity**

```
        Retrofit retrofit  = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(" http://sales.erprnd.com/api/v2/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

   Call<GeoTag> geoTagCall =  apiInterface.postGeoTagData(geoTagUserData, CustCode, "Bearer "+body.getToken() );
   geoTagCall.enqueue(new Callback<GeoTag>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<GeoTag> call, Response<GeoTag> response) {

           Toast.makeText(GeoTaggingActivity.this, ""+response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<GeoTag> call, Throwable t) {
           Toast.makeText(GeoTaggingActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
```

When I use Postman the response is 201 AND Response IS {} which is ok. My jsonObject is

```
{
 "latitude":11.22,
 "longitude":22.11,
 "alt_address":"test address",
 "height":"12 ft",
 "width":"24 ft",
 "photo": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMAAAAD"
}
```

I Have created another class where i get all information from user which is 
**geoTagUserData** i get all the info perfectly

Please Help me find the error .

Comment: Can you also check what error its throwing with status 500?

Comment: okhttp3.ResoponseBody$1@5733e16 when i use thre response.errorBody()

Comment: Are you using HttpLoggingInterceptor? If not then use it to see the exact request and response .

Comment: You're printing the object identifier, not the actual error. Not only that, you're calling errorBody() in onResponse which is called when the status code is successful. I recommend you start reading some guides on Retrofit. It's actually really simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got The Solution which is, When I Send Data to Send Data to server from My App it just get the value against every field form **geoTagUserData** Class it doesn't 
`@post` Converted Data in `JSON` Format. When My Server Find That I just Values Not In `JSON` Format
Then It Just Rejected And **Return 500 error**

> So, My solution is just Using **Gson Converter** get The value form
>   user and Converted it to `JSON` object. and Send That to Server Which will **Return 201**